How to disribute spotlights to provide best light results?
I'm working on wiring spotlights for my basement, which includes three bedrooms, two bathrooms, a kitchen, and a hall. Each room has different dimensions.
For example, I have a rectangular room measuring 3m x 2m. I want to distribute the spotlights so that the light is as evenly distributed as possible across the room.
I initially tried placing the spotlights equidistant from each other. I divided the 3m length by 3 spotlights, placing them 1m apart, with each light half a meter from the walls. For the 2m width, I used 2 spotlights, placing them 1m apart and half a meter from the walls. However, this setup doesn't seem to provide adequate lighting as there are large gaps between the lights.

How can I determine the right number of spotlights for a room of length ( L ) and width ( W ), and how should I distribute them to achieve the best lighting results?

you have a basement which includes three bedrooms, two bathrooms, a kitchen, and a hall.

@Traveler Yes! i am not sure are you asking or stating a fact!!

JUST SURPRISED ABOUT THE SIZE OF YOUR BASEMENT, is it above ground or below (windows)

[Frame challenge, not actually answering the number/distribution question] One method might be to vary the distance the bulb is from the actual ceiling: the further it is buried, the narrower the light cone. Some recessed lights have the bulb recessed but the "top" actually just poking out of its hole, for this reason.

You need to overlap your light boundaries.  In your case, you'd need to shift each row closer to the long wall, and add another row in the middle, with the lights offset—a triangular pattern, rather than square.  Or use lamps with a wider throw.


decide the illumination level for the room, lux or footcandles.

So given the illumination needed, divide by the output of one lamp. That tells you how many you need.

once you know how many then you can work out a pattern - also consider if you need focused illumination for particular activities like reading or sewing.


